# Migrate only taxonomy terms from a specific vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

When doing a D7->8 migration, my taxonomy term migration template imports all the taxonomy terms found in the source D7 site. How to filter only the terms that belong to a specific vocabulary? For a node, I simply said:

```
source:
 plugin: d7_node
 node_type: article
```

But for terms? Is there something similar?

```
source:
 plugin: d7_taxonomy_term
 ????
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
source:
  plugin: d7_taxonomy_term
  bundle: tags
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! BTW is the Yaml file structure for migrations documented somewhere? Or do I have to look in the source code/templates?

Comment: I don't think there something like complete reference to date. The best is to look directly into the code - search for plugin id (d7_taxonomy_term in this case) and then look for $this->configuration in the found class and its parent classes to see the variables that the plugin uses.

Comment: In addition, most of the classes are described well in phpdoc at the beginning of the class (it's not the case of d7/Term, unfortunately..)